# The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object - revised

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am using EF in .NET V4.0 in Visual Basic (VS2010) with SQL Compact Edition 4.0.  We are building a set of simple forms to maintain some tables.  One table 'Companies' is linked to 2 other tables (People,CalibrationInfo) with Companies as the parent table.  The Entity Type Definition is:
<EntityType Name="Company">
          <Documentation>
            <Summary>Provides a list of Companies and shipping addresses.</Summary>
          </Documentation>
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="CompanyID" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="CompanyID" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" annotation:StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="Name" Type="String" MaxLength="100" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="Address1" Type="String" MaxLength="100" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
          <Property Name="Address2" Type="String" MaxLength="100" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
          <Property Name="Address3" Type="String" MaxLength="100" Unicode="true" FixedLength="false" />
          <Property Name="Telephone" Type="String" MaxLength="30" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" />
          <Property Name="PrimaryContactID" Type="Int32" a:GetterAccess="Public" xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/codegeneration" a:SetterAccess="Public" Nullable="true" >
            <Documentation>
              <Summary>Optional Primary Contact ID for the primary contact for this company.</Summary>
            </Documentation>
          </Property>
          <Property Name="Disabled" Type="Boolean" Nullable="false" DefaultValue="false" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="Calibrations" Relationship="NWCUDataStoreModel.FK_CalibrationInfo_Company" FromRole="Companies" ToRole="CalibrationInfo" />
          <NavigationProperty Name="PrimaryContact" Relationship="NWCUDataStoreModel.FK_Company_PrimaryContact" FromRole="Company" ToRole="Person" />
</EntityType>
The form uses a binding source set to the Company set in the context:
    bsCompanies = ctx.Companies.OrderBy("it.Name")

The Binding Source is linked to a Navigation Bar.  Pressing the BindingNavigatorAddNewItem button gets a new record created.  I enter only the company name tab to the next field and press the Save button.  The link to the Primary Contact is set to nothing so there are no other relationships for this record.  The Save button executes the following:
    RowsSaved = ctx.SaveChanges()
This generates the InvalidOperationException.  The Inner exception is:
AcceptChanges cannot continue because the object's key values conflict with another object...

There are no other records in the database with the name set to 'Test'.  The exception indicates that the record was saved, but was unable to accept the changes.  The record is still marked as Added.  Calling ctx.AcceptChanges after this error generates an exception.

If I were doing this directly in code, instead of with BindingSource on a form, it would essentially look like this:
    dim company as New Company
    company.Name="Test"
    company.PrimaryContactID = nothing
    ctx.Companies.Add(company)
    ctx.Save

I have looked at other examples of this on multipe sites, and have applied any fixes I could find, including setting the PrimaryContact id directly to a the correct Person record ID and setting the PrimaryContact to Nothing.  Nothing makes any difference.

I have also deleted the three tables from the model and then reloaded them.  No difference.

I have used this same code with no problems in SQL Server, but almost nothing seems to work with SQL Compact edition V4.0.  You would think it should not be so difficult to store a single record into a table.  If we have to go back to data sets, I have a lot of recoding to do.

Any suggestions or insights appreciated.
Thanks, Neil

Comment: Can you provide some code instead of explanations?

Comment: Vitaly - my apologies - my first question on the board and the xml and code blocks were not formatted correctly. See above for corrections and hopefully more detail.  In summary, I have a simple form, with a binding source connected to a SQL Compact 4.0 datab ase and am trying to add one record to a table with a single link to another table - although the link field is null.

Comment: I have now removed the link to the Person - it is now a simple table with absolutely no links to any other table.  Still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, the answer to this was to use Nuget to download Entity Framework 6.0, Entity Framework SQL Server Compact and Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0.  I then downloaded the EF Framework 5 DB Generator .tt file as the EF 6 version does not work in Visual Studio 2010. You do this from the Add Code Generation menu item, and select Online Templates->EF 5 DBContext Generator...  Finally, I modified the file using this Microsoft article: [Databinding with WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx).  After that, things started to work.  EF 4.0 does not work with SQL Server Compact, out of the box, without the changes described above.  Using the ObservableListSource class described in the article also helped with parent-child relationships on forms, which did not work until I switched to this class.